# Make absolute work inside filtering in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to return a percentage of results from a dataset. Being a noob in Scala, tried the following

`ds.filter(abs(hash(col("source"))) % 100 < percentage)`

but getting abs cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Column). I don't want to sample it, I want to return based on the hash of a column so that it's deterministic even when dataset changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine:

```
ds.filter(abs(hash(col("source"))) % 100 < percentage)
```

Probabely you have multiple `abs` in your namespace (e.g. from imports like `import math._` etc. To be sure, use

```
ds.filter(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.abs(hash(col("source"))) % 100 < percentage)
```

But I think this will not garantee that you get the exact percentage, because hash values may not be equally distributed (think about a dataframe with only 1 unique value of `source`, hash values will all be the same.... you get either all records or none. To get the exact percentage, you would need something like :

```
val newDF = df
 .withColumn("rnb",row_number().over(Window.orderBy($"source"))) // or order by hash if you wish
 .withColumn("count",count("*").over())
 .where($"rnb" < lit(fraction)*$"count")
```